# Global variable not being retained in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

so I'm trying to get a variable containing the name of a PDF file I wish to open in a UIweb View to show up in a label. I first identify the global variable in a seperate class here:

header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
extern NSString *PDFNameString; 
extern NSString *PDFActualName; 
@interface GlobalVars : NSObject
{

}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *PDFActualName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *PDFNameString;
@end
```

.m:

```
#import "GlobalVars.h"
NSString *PDFNameString; 
NSString *PDFActualName; //the name of the PDF file

@implementation GlobalVars
{

}

@end
```

then I have the menu where I have an alert dialog featuring a text field so that the user can input the PDF name:

.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GlobalVars.h"

@interface TitleViewController : UIViewController{
    NSFileManager *FM1;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *OpenPDF;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *ViewPDF;

-(void)OpeningPDF;
-(void)alertView;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "TitleViewController.h"

@interface TitleViewController ()

@end

@implementation TitleViewController

UIAlertView * alert;
UITextField *textField;
int StopTheAlerts = 0;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    FM1 = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)ButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    self.OpeningPDF; 
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [_OpenPDF release];
    [_ViewPDF release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)OpeningPDF
{
    StopTheAlerts = 0;
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
    initWithTitle:@"Please enter a valid PDF name below:"
    message:@"(Please add .PDF on the end!) \n \n"
    delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
    otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
    textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    textField.delegate = nil;
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
    textField.frame = CGRectMake(15, 90, 255, 30);
    textField.placeholder = @"PDF name";
    textField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert; //set up an alert box with a text field
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    [alert addSubview:textField];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    PDFNameString = textField.text; //set the PDF name variable to the name entered
    PDFActualName = textField.text; 
    NSArray *Paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *DocumentDir = [Paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *TempFilePath = PDFNameString; 
    PDFNameString = [DocumentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:TempFilePath];
    if([FM1 fileExistsAtPath: PDFNameString]){
        _ViewPDF.enabled = true; 
    }
    else {
        while(StopTheAlerts <= 0){
            UIAlertView *ErrorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
            initWithTitle:@"This file dosn't exist!"
            message:@"Please reenter the file name!"
            delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
            otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [ErrorAlert show];
            [ErrorAlert release];
            StopTheAlerts = 1;
        }
    }

}
@end
```

This part all works fine, however, when I switch over the the view that contains the UIWebView to actually view the PDF (I've removed that in this part of the code) it has the old "message sent to deallocated instance 0xdb8fca0" error when I try to assign my global variable to the label containing the PDF name, this error also occurs when trying to get the UIWebView to read the PDF using the other global variable.

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GlobalVars.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *PDFNameL;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _PDFNameL.text = PDFActualName;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [_PDFNameL release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

@end

If anyone knows a solution to the problem I would be very happy

thanks

Comment: Something is missing in the first .h file you posted. There's an `@end` but no `@interface` and braces that are just kind of hanging out.

Comment: 1) This was tagged Xcode 4. Are you really using such an out-of-date version? 2) You are not using automatic reference counting (ARC). Why not? 3) Why are you using global variable for your properties in GlobalVars? 4) DO you realize your are not creating instance variable, but file global variables, in your TitleViewController class? 5) Don't put ivar declarations in a .h file. This is all bad.

Comment: I need global variables to interact between the TitleViewController and View controller class. I am using Xcode 4.5 so I can edit for IOS 6. and as for the first .h file, I may have accidentally deleted the interface bit when I copied it over, it is there in the actual code

Comment: there, I added in the interface. The reason I have global variable properties in my globals class is because I was sticking them in there to see if it fixed my problem, it didn't (obviously) but I haven't got round to removing them yet.

Comment: Why aren't you using ARC???

Comment: not entirely sure how to, could you link me a tutorial on that, I'm kind new to OC

Comment: 'it has the old "message sent to deallocated instance 0xdb8fca0" error when I try to assign my global variable to the label containing the PDF name' - here you are presumably referring to code such as `_PDFNameL.text = PDFActualName;`. The message here is being sent to whatever `_PDFNameL` is referencing, that the value (RHS) is coming from a global variable is not relevant. It seems you are looking in the wrong place, however bad using global variables here is design-wise that does not appear to be your actual problem at all. Use the debugger and look into the LHS - why is it deallocated?

Comment: yeah, I found that out later. I've managed to fix and finish off the app now however, so all's well I geuss.